# When using generic React components, get error in TS 3.2+

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0

This code compiles just fine with TypeScript 3.1.x

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IErrorProps {
    error: string;
}

export default function foo<TErrorProps extends IErrorProps>(
    ErrorCmp: React.ComponentType<TErrorProps>
) {
    return () => {
        return <ErrorCmp error="test error" />;
    }
}
```

But if I compile it with TypeScript 3.2 or newer, I get

```
 error TS2322: Type '{ error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TErrorProps'.
```

Is this a regression in TS 3.2 or did 3.2 fix a loophole my code was taking advantage of?

Interestingly, this code fails to compile in 3.1 as well

```
interface IErrorProps {
    error: string;
}

export default function foo<TErrorProps extends IErrorProps>(
    ErrorCmp: (props: TErrorProps) => string
) {
    return () => {
        return ErrorCmp({ error: 'test error' });
    }
}
```

with the error

```
Argument of type '{ error: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TErrorProps'
```

Comment: I am getting errors compiling with ts 3.2+ in react-apollo, which I believe are the same issue. It seems like quite a bad change, so I am surprised to not find too many people hitting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is correct. Consider the following:

```
foo<{error: string, whatever: number}>(obj => `${obj.error} (${obj.whatever})`);
```

This is valid under the constraints of your generic, as `{error: string, whatever: number}` extends `{error: string}`.

But you are calling it with only the `error` key. It is almost guaranteed to be invalid.

Comment: That does make sense, seems TS 3.2 basically fixed a bug here. Thanks!